# How to show details of a model that is related with other one?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need that when the URL for example, localhost:8000/apirest/customers

Customers is a table that is asigned a table Role and I need to show all fields of Role

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Phone =  models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Role(models.Model):
        Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Description = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Premium = models.BooleanField()
```

This is only an example, what I need that the Json show something like this

```
{
     "Id":1,
     "Name":"Jhon Carter",
     "Adress": "Lombard Street"
     "Phone": "25 56592552",
     "Role":{
           "Id":1,
           "Description":"Description 1"
           "Premium": true
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Jorge.

First of all does your models compiles successfully? because in this line:

```
Role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I get `Undefined Role` which is because Role definition is in the next lines. So I changed the model definitions to this:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    class MyRole(models.Model):
        Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Description = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Premium = models.BooleanField()

    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Role = models.ForeignKey(MyRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What you want to do is [serializing relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) which for your case would be something like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from core.models import Customer


class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer.MyRole
        fields = ['Id', 'Description', 'Premium']


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Role = RoleSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['Id', 'Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Role']
```